# Get value between a range of two values from percentage

Tags: c#, percentage

1. Let's say I have a range of two values:
   5...........98

and let's assume the user position's the slider at value 40

1. Now I want to get the value from another range of values at the exact percentage position as from range 1

let's say the second range of values are 10.........80

```
int nRange1 = 98 - 5;
int nRange2 = 80 - 10;

int nValue1 = 40;

int nPercentOnRange1 = ((nValue1 - 5) / nRange1)*100;
```

Now I have to get the value from Range2 at the exact percentage as nPercentOnRange1, but I don't know how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First need to find % from first range and apply that % to new range.

Here is what I will do:
Range1(A to B)   Selected value: c
Range2(E to F)

Range1 % = (C-A) / (B-A) * 100

Range 2 corresponding value = ((F - E) * (Range 1 %) / 100) + E

C#:

```
 int Range1Min = 5, Range1Max=90, Range1SelectedValue = 40;
 int Range2Min = 6, Range2Max=80;
 decimal range1Percent = (Range1SelectedValue-Range1Min ) / (Range1Max-Range1Min) * 100.0
 decimal range2NewValue = (Range2Max - Range2Min) * range1Percent  / 100 + Range2Min;
```

Answer (score 1):

The value you need is

```
x = 10 + nRange2 * nPercentOnRange1 / 100.0
```

Let me explain why. You need a number `x` such that

```
((x - 10) / nRange2) * 100.0 = nPercentOnRange1
```

Therefore, just solve for `x`.

```
((x - 10) / nRange2) * 100.0 = nPercentOnRange1 =>
((x - 10) / nRange2) = nPercentOnRange1 / 100.0 =>
x - 10 = nRange2 * nPercentOnRange1 / 100.0 =>
x = 10 + nRange2 * nPercentOnRange1 / 100.0
```

And note that this actually makes intuitive sense. We're saying take the percentage, scale that into the length of the second range (that's what `nRange2 * nPercentOnRange1 / 100.0`) is doing and then add that to the lower bound of the second range. Basically we are saying step `nPercentOnRange1` percent into the second range. That's *exactly* what the formula is expressing.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for

```
int nPercentOnRange1 = ((nValue1 - 5)/ nRange1) * 100;
```

ending up as zero since `nValue1` and `nRange1` are integers. This might be better:

```
int nPercentOnRange1 = ((nValue1 - 5) * 100 / nRange1);
```

Then you can do

```
  int nValue2 = 10 + nPercentOnRange1*nRange2/100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work:

```
nValue2 = nPercentage1 * nRange2 / 100 + 10
```